# <base> href not working in Firefox for <iframe>

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, iframe

I have a website that minimally looks like the following:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <iframe id="a"></iframe>
 </body>
</html>
```

And javascript that at some point does something like this:

```
$('#a').attr('srcdoc', '
 <html>
  <head>
   <base href="https://example.com/" target="_blank">
  </head>
  <body>
   <a href="./some_relative_link">Foo</a>
  </body>
 </html>');
```

The link works fine in Chrome and IE, that is, it goes to `https://example.com/some_relative_link`, but in Firefox, the `href` attribute of the `base` element doesn't do anything and it just tries to access the link as if it were local to the outer site.

Is this a known issue? Design feature? Bug? Any help would be appreciated.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4c0zjctx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a [known bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1238804). It should be fixed in Firefox 46.